# How can I find the formula for this sequence (series?)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Apologies for the poor explanation, I haven't done maths for so long and I'm not at all sure what you would even call a problem like this, so it's probably in the wrong forum. I'm sure it's actually really simple but I just don't know where to start with it.

I'm trying to work out the formula that will give these results:

- x = 0 when i = 0 and j = 0
- x = 1 when i = 0 and j = 1
- x = 2 when i = 0 and j = 2
- ...etc
- x = 9 when i = 0 and j = 9
- x = 1 when i = 1 and j = 0
- x = 2 when i = 1 and j = 1
- x = 3 when i = 1 and j = 2
- ...etc
- x = 0 when i = 1 and j = 9
- x = 2 when i = 2 and j = 0
- x = 3 when i = 2 and j = 1
- x = 4 when i = 2 and j = 2
- ...etc
- x = 1 when i = 2 and j = 9
  -... etc etc

I know this poorly formatted but I can't think of any other way of expressing it.

I really can't get my head around this. It seems like

x = (i + j)

works for most of it then somehow it 'resets' with something like:

x = (i + j) - 10

but that's obviously ridiculous. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it because I'm pretty clueless right now.

Thanks.

Comment: $x = (i+j) \bmod{10}$.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah mods! Thank you so much!